# Render goes black after it's done

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

While I was working on my scene I, decided to give it a render, and it was all going really well but just when it was about to finish Rendering, whole the render Image turned black.

Just like that: !

[image]

Compositor :

[image]

Comment: Do you have any composite nodes?

Comment: Yep, I do have some

Comment: Could you post your compositing node setup? Do you have any strip in the video sequence editor?

Comment: No, I wasn't creating anything in video sequence editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the compositor is not getting any input, I think.
you can connect the "image" output of the rgb node ALSO to the compositor, which builds the output. Just drag it.

you can leave the viewer connected, to see the result of that (or others) node output, too, like the backdrop, if you use it.

Answer (score 4):

The *Composite Node* is not connected.

As well as for the *Viewer Node* you have to connect the RGB Curve Node to the Composite Node